# Grails: how to set a meta-constraint on domain class property?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a Contact class that belongs to a Subscription and I want to set a hypothetic readonly constraint on the subscription property, to be consumed in the scaffold templates.

The class looks like

```
class Contact {

   static belongsTo = [subscription: Subscription]

   static constraints = {
     subscription(nullable: false, readonly: true) // hypothetic *readonly* constraint
     name(blank: false)
     email(blank: false, email: true)
   }

   Integer id
   String name
   String email
   String description
}
```

I found [ConstrainedProperty.addMetaConstraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/validation/ConstrainedProperty.html#addMetaConstraint%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method that "adds a meta constraints which is a non-validating informational constraint".

How do I call it from within the Domain class?

And how do I get the meta-constraint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the scaffolding templates there is a property domainClass from type org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsDomainClass. These object has the property constrainedProperties. To have excess to the 'readonly' you have to do this:

Your domain class:

```
class Contact {
   static belongsTo = [subscription: Subscription]

   static constraints = {
       subscription(nullable: false, attributes: [readonly: true])  
   }

   String description
}
```

in the scaffolding template:

```
def ro = domainClass.constrainedProperties.subscription.attributes.readonly
```

the DefaultGrailsDomainClass has a constructor with a attribute from type Class maybe you can do this:

```
def domainClass = new DefaultGrailsDomainClass(Contact.class)
def ro = domainClass.constrainedProperties.subscription.attributes.readonly
```

Maybe there is a Factory for this, but I don't know.

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to define the constraint as a map: `subscription(attributes: [myConstraint: true])`. The constraint is also available on the `cp` instance used in `renderEditor.template`, e.g. `cp.attributes.myConstraint`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried yours a few more ways and received compilation errors; I'm going to update your answer to use a map - feel free to revert if if I'm in the wrong. I'll give you the +1.

Comment: @Rob My mistake. In the last time write a lot in javascrip.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if that was the case. I find myself doing the same thing sometimes.

Comment: Confirm that it works for me and it's what I was looking for. +! I'm surprised there is no use case for addMetaConstraint though... do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want a `readonly` constraint that influences the scaffolded form fields, you can use:

```
static constraints = {
    subscription(editable: false)
}
```

Here's a list of the constraints that are used by `renderEditor.template` (that I could find with a quick search, anyway):

- editable (if `false`, causes rendered field to be readonly - works for String and Date fields)
- widget (if 'textarea', field is rendered as a textarea - works for String fields)
- format (for date fields, supplies the constraint value to the datePicker's format attribute)

Comment: I managed to display a oneToMany property (subscription in my example) as read-only setting the editable:false constraint and tweaking the renderEditor.temlpate to consider it.

I can't add an arbitrary property though: I have no errors when loading the domain class, but I get a "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: inline for class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty" in renderEditor.template on the line cp.myCustomConstraint.

Comment: @Xan - You're right. I don't know why I thought that worked, apologies for misleading. I'm gonna try out Medrod's answer out of curiosity. I've removed the second half of my answer, but will keep it around for the first part.

Comment: There, I moved my comment down to reinstate the order. Have a look at my comment on Merdod's answer - his is pretty close to right, although I had to modify it a bit to get it to work for me.

Comment: for me, using editable: flase in the constraints had zero effect on the scaffolded UI - it could still be edited.  e.g.   "lastLoggedIn nullable: true, editable: false" still allowed lastLoggedIn to be editable, even though I want it to be purely system generated (so read only to the user).  grails 2.4.4.